# Curved arrow in math mode

Tags: diagrams, arrows

I'm fairly new to LaTeX and am trying to see if I can get away doing something *without* using a library like tikzcd. I have the following code:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
$\dashrightarrow 
\overbrace{Tr1_{P9} \mapsto \underbrace{enum(Tr2_{P9} 
\mapsto Tr3_{P9})}_{\alpha} \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix} Tr4_{P9} \\ Tr4_{I0} \end{pmatrix}}^{\beta}$
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]
\

Is there a way that I can have a long curved arrow (preferably a dotted \mapsto arrow) connect from the first letters, Tr1_{P9} to the vector at the end––over or under the rest of the text–– without creating a diagram in tikzcd? The overbrace (with the \beta text) can be changed to an underbrace if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without creating a diagram, you can do that with `pstricks`: make two nodes in the equation and connect them with `ncarc` and the suitable parameters:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator{\enum}{enum}

\usepackage{pst-node}

\begin{document}

 \[ \dashrightarrow
\overbrace{\rnode{T}{Tr1}_{P9} \mapsto \underbrace{\enum(Tr2_{P9}
\mapsto Tr3_{P9})}_{\alpha} \mapsto
\begin{pmatrix} Tr4_{P9} \\Tr\rnode{M}{4_{I0}}\end{pmatrix}}^{\beta}
\ncarc[linestyle=dotted, dotsep=2pt, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.15, arcangle=-30, nodesep=6pt]{T}{ M}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]